# Form changed to HTML and posts to PHP on ASP page

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, asp-classic

I posted a question before about a form submitting to asp. I am more familiar with php so I decided to change the form to submit to php instead. The only thing is the form is created within an asp file contact.asp and I have submitted this to a contact.php page.

The problem is I am now trying to include validation into the head section of the asp page using JavaScript this is for an empty name, email and phone check. I have first tried just the name and email as:

The JavaScript I am using is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x==null || x=="") {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}

function validateForms() {
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
  }
} 

</script>
```

I would highly appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Edit: The JavaScript is not working it just submits the form without any validation

Comment: Are you intentionally declaring the same function twice?

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt sorry it is a bit late and I'm not too great at JavaScript. I changed it to validateForms() for the email validation and it still sends the form without any validation. Thanks

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt I did change the name of the function to validateForms() this did not work. How can I merge the functions? I have even tried removing the email validation and the name validation does not even work on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the same function twice. That won't work. Rename one of the functions or merge them as one.

Also, make sure to actually call the function.

```
<form method="" action="" onsubmit="return validateForms();" id="myForm">
```

And make sure that the fields are called correctly.

```
<input name="email" type="email" />
```